# HTML & CSS working with images of different shapes

Tags: html, css

As some of you guys may know allowing users to upload images can be a hassle and especially if you have to create some sort of list with them.

I have been looking all over the web and have been unable to find concrete answers to what you do in the case where you need to show a list of images of different shapes. Therefor i turn to you.

Say **User 1** uploads the following image:

[image]

And **User 2** uploads this image:

[image]

As you can see these two images are very different in both height and width.

Now lets say that you have 10 images of different sizes and wish to display them in a grid 4 by 4 (for this purpose i use `ng-repeat` to show a loop)

```
<div class="col-xs-4" ng-repeat="image in images">
    <img alt="" ng-src="{{image}}">
</div>
```

if you do this, this will create a list that is uneven! and will look very "ugly" to say the least.

So my question is what do you do? Are there any tricks using `CSS` to make it fit any images of any size so that everything is aligned?

I hope my description of the problem was accurate enough for the sake of demonstration here is a fiddle that shows this issue as well.

***In short how do i make sure they are all the same size without making one of the images look cramped and / or distorting the individual image?***

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27998/)

Comment: If they're different aspect ratios and you want to display them evenly you will have to ... a) crop them - maybe a centered square is best for this, or b) place them in a container with space around them. Which option would suit you better?

Comment: this doesn't solve the solution of cropping at all, but bootstrap has `clearfix` classes to aid with this. adding a clearfix element every 3rd element will break into a new line: http://jsfiddle.net/jn6nnp3d/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, one option is to crop all the images to a suitable format, a square might be a good compromise. You can do this by wrapping your images in a container first, and positioning the image in relation to the container. Example:

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/


/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.image-container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="image-container"><img src="http://pngimg.com/upload/girls_PNG6448.png" width="100%" height="100%" class="image image-responsive"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="image-container">

        <img class="image image-responsive" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://yeemei.mobile9.com/download/media/442/niceandsim_s8mhs1do.jpeg"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="http://pngimg.com/upload/girls_PNG6448.png" width="100%" height="100%" class="image image-responsive"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img class="image image-responsive" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://yeemei.mobile9.com/download/media/442/niceandsim_s8mhs1do.jpeg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctvj7e0r/)

You can also position the image in the container. For example if you wanted to center it you could add:

```
    top: -100%;
    bottom: -100%;
    left: -100%;
    right: -100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to provide the users with a cropper to your preferred ratio and allow them to select the part of the image to show.

An alternative is to use the images as background on a `div` with specific ratio and hope that it does not show irrelevant areas.

Here is a solution for the second case (*with a - just for laughs - animation to show the whole of the image*)

http://jsfiddle.net/mrccf3sv/

```css
.image{
  display:block;
  background: url('') 50% 0% no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  animation:pan 10s linear infinite alternate;
  }
.image:before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  padding-top:56.25%; /*ratio of 16:9*/
}
```

---

And see it responsive by using different bootstrap column count for each breakpoint.
http://jsfiddle.net/mrccf3sv/1

Answer (score 0):

Scaling with CSS is incredibly bad practice. I mean, we all have to do it sometimes, but if you CAN scale server-side, better do that. Try PHP's imagick, if available.